# What it happened when i use FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://loacalhost:9000/filepath"), conf)?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata, rpc

I was confused in a project that it require me to optimization small file support for HDFS.
Its step is like this:

1. Store small file to HBase;
2. Several small file merger to a big file and than store to HDFS;
3. Use some tactics to record those small file's position;
4. We need guarantee the file's URI is consistent.

And then in my study i meet a problem. For example,
If i use command

`hdfs fs -put ~/local/smallfile /usr/smallfile`.

if we don't do anything, then in my code it could be like this

`FileSystem.get(URI.create("hdfs://loacalhost:9000/usr/smallfile"), conf)`.

But if my project is OK, the small file should be store to HBase, then when i use the URI `hdfs://loacalhost:9000/usr/smallfile` in my code, and it should return `NULL`.

The problem is, how could i redirect to HBase and return it back. I read the RPC and still can't get any help.

My idea is add a server between user and hdfs, it could get all URI request and stop it then do something in it. But i don't know how. And does it feasible on technique?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to read HBase file directly from hdfs is not a good idea as the naming is not predictable. Also, the performance will be really bad.
If your file max size is few MB's then you can store it in HBase and use HBase api to fetch data. 
**Store 1 file in 1 cell and then you will be able to retrieve it easily via HBase api. You can also use HBase stargate to fetch files via Http Rest call.**